# Is it possible for someone to setup ROS for me?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And have it be for windows? What about for Windows XP?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224080/is-it-possible-for-someone-to-setup-ros-for-me?/) by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-01-13

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if it's possible to have ROS working on Windows. But you can find some answers  [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41347/how-to-install-ros-on-windows/) :

or using a virtual machine on your windows system :
http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/ROS-Installation-for-Windows-Users/137.html

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0